# Nested partials in Clojure

Tags: clojure

How does the data structure get evaluated with the nested `partial`s in the following:`((partial (partial - 3)6)9)`. The inner `partial` yields -3, then we have `((partial -3)9)`.
But how why does partial then makes (-3 `-` 9)? Where does it get the subtraction instruction from?

I would like some helps about the manner of reading and evaluating of this data representation by Clojure.

Comment: exactly, i know this. thats why the question!

Comment: Does the answer, as extended, now make sense?

Comment: Backing up, conceptually, it's important to realize that the `-` function accepts both more and fewer than two arguments.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The claim that `((partial - 3) 6)` is called during the course of evaluating this expression is incorrect, and this is at the core of the misunderstanding.

To make this simpler, let's break down:

```
((partial (partial - 3) 6) 9)
```

...instead, rewriting it as:

```
(let [p1 (partial - 3)]
  ((partial p1 6) 9)
```

Now, what does `(partial p1 6)` return? A function which calls `p1`, with its first argument being `6`, and any subsequent arguments appended. Thus, we could again write it more verbosely as:

```
(let [p1 (partial - 3)
      p2 (partial p1 6)]
  (p2 9)
```

Thus, `(p2 9)` calls `(p1 6 9)`, which calls `(- 3 6 9)`. `(- 3 6)` is never invoked anywhere in the execution process, so the initial function call of `-` is never consumed until the final invocation with all arguments present.

(The actual implementation may optimize the middle call away, folding p1's arguments into p2, but there's no need to incorporate such optimizations into the conceptual model; behavior is equivalent to the above).

Comment: thanks. i didnt claim that (partial - 3) yields -3, what i meant was that ((partial - 3)6) yields -3 which then will be passed as the arg to the outer partial.

Comment: @amirteymuri `((partial - 3) 6)` does indeed yield -3, but that expression is not present anywhere in the code for your question! Rather, you have `(partial (partial - 3) 6)`, which is quite a different thing indeed, as Charles Duffy explains in his answer.

Comment: @amalloy, thank you for that restatement -- that actually helped me better understand the original question, and thus to amend this to be more on-point.